# What is this timeformat?

Tags: swift

I want to use DateFormatter

but I don't know this time format

in Swift

```
let date = "2017-04-22T15:42:35.000Z"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd........"
print(dateFormatter.date(from: date))
```

2017-04-22T15:42:35.000Z

"yyyy-MM-dd...."

Comment: What does MySQL have to do with your question?

Comment: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 0):

```
let date = "2017-04-22T15:42:35.000Z"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
print(dateFormatter.date(from: date))
```

This must be what you are looking for.